# How to add a branch-type tag to a previously created branch in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

When I create a new branch through Bitbucket I have the possibility to tag the new branch. If I tag it as "Feature", then the branch will start with "feature/".

What if I already have branches that start with "feature" but they have no tag? Could I add the "Feature" tag to them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the "Branch type" field (Bugfix, Feature, Hotfix, etc) in the "Create branch" dialog?

[image]

If yes, there's no difference between a branch created with branch type "Feature" and another created with branch type "Custom" if it has the "feature/" prefix. You don't need to add any "tag" to it (you can't actually).

[image]

Comment: I’m talking about that. However, I firstly create a branch with “feature/“ prefix and no tag and then I create another one with the tag “Feature” and the forced “feature/“ prefix. If I filter by branch type “Feature”, only the second one is shown.

Comment: I tested here (Bitbucket server v6.3.2) and it worked like expected. Both branches (the one created with branch type "Feature" and the other with branch type "Custom" but with the "feature/" prefix are showed when I fill the filter field with "feature/". I updated the answer with this info.